# How to generate a table with all the chess notation

Tags: chess, xskak

I like to learn how to create a listing of all the chess moves in a table.

In my MWE, I manually enter in the 1st three moves. Is there a way I can do it through looping?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{skak, xskak,chessboard}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\noindent
\mainline{
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 Bg4 4.dxe5 Bxf3 5.Qxf3 dxe5 6.Bc4 Nf6 7.Qb3 Qe7 8.Nc3 c6 9.Bg5 b5 10.Nxb5 cxb5 11.Bxb5+ Nbd7 12.O-O-O Rd8 13.Rxd7 Rxd7 14.Rd1 Qe6 15.Bxd7+ Nxd7 16.Qb8+ Nxb8 17.Rd8#}


\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} |  }
    \hline\textbf{Move}&\textbf{White}&\textbf{Black}\\
    \hline
    1 & e4 & e5\\
    \hline
    2 & Nf3 & d6\\
    \hline
    3 & d4 & Bg4 \\
    \hline
}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please make your example compilable. With the current code I get a xcolor option clash(Can be fixed by just deleting `\usepackage[...]{xcolor}` and a unmatched `}` (The single `}` in the line before `\end{tabular}`)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. My codes work in Overleaf. But I will take adopt your suggestions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Creating a tabular with loops is not easy, as tabular cells build groups. Normally the best is to assemble the content of the tabular in a macro and to use this. E.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\PassOptionsToPackage{table}{xcolor}
\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{comment}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
\newchessgame
\noindent
\mainline{
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 d6 3.d4 Bg4 4.dxe5 Bxf3 5.Qxf3 dxe5 6.Bc4 Nf6 7.Qb3 Qe7 8.Nc3 c6 9.Bg5 b5 10.Nxb5 cxb5 11.Bxb5+ Nbd7 12.O-O-O Rd8 13.Rxd7 Rxd7 14.Rd1 Qe6 15.Bxd7+ Nxd7 16.Qb8+ Nxb8 17.Rd8#}

\newcommand\tabularcontent{}
\whiledo{\xskaktestmoveid
{\xskakget{movenr}}{\xskakget{player}}}
{%
 \ifthenelse{\equal{\xskakget{player}}{w}}
 {%
  \eappto\tabularcontent
   {\xskakget{movenr}&
    \noexpand\xskakset{moveid=\xskakget{moveid}}%
    \noexpand\xskakget{lan}&}%
 }
 {%
  \eappto\tabularcontent
   {\noexpand\xskakset{moveid=\xskakget{moveid}}}
  \appto\tabularcontent{\xskakget{lan}\\\hline}% 
 }
 \xskakset{stepmoveid}
}%
\ifthenelse{\equal{\xskakgetgame{lastplayer}}{w}}{\appto\tabularcontent{\\\hline}}{}


\vspace{1cm}
\begin{tabular}{ | p{2cm} | p{2cm} | p{2cm} |  }
    \hline\textbf{Move}&\textbf{White}&\textbf{Black}\\\hline
    \tabularcontent
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for teaching me.